# python incrementing character loops

Tags: python, python-3.x

ok I am working on trying to create a incremental listing loop.

Hoping to achieve a loop that does something of the following:
loop through charset1 a-Z. If no matches found add to loop so aa-ZZ and so on. Can't seem to find a good way to do the loop.

```
import itertools
result = "password"
charset1 = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
charset2 = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']
charcount = 1

while i != result
    finalchar = charset1[-1]
    finalset = charset1[-1] * charcount
    for check in
```

Comment: You can save yourself a lot of work by defining `charset1 = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"` etc., or by `import string; charset1 = string.lowercase; charset2 = string.letters`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following which uses `itertools.product` with the `repeat` parameter as a template:

```
from string import ascii_letters
from itertools import product

for i in range(1, 3): # do 1 and 2 chars
    chars = product(ascii_letters, repeat=i)
    for combo in chars:
        print(''.join(combo))
```

Comment: [EDIT] nvm figured it out. Thank you for your help.